How to specify where json files are stored using flutter?
I have been using the diagram_editor package (https://pub.dev/packages/diagram_editor/example) and trying to understand how it serializes json files.
I am trying to look at a serialized json file so I can create some to be deserialzed, but for various reasons (permission, etc.) have either not been able to find where they are stored on any of the Android devices I have been using, or not been able to access "hidden" folders.
How can I change the serialization policy?
